# The field <fieldName> is assigned but its value is never used

Tags: c#, .net, warnings

I'm writing a Web Api class of the form:

```
public class PartController : ApiController
{
    private ILogService _logService;
    private IPartSerive _partService;
    private const string className = "My.Long.Full.ClassPath.PartController";

    ...

    [HttpGet]
    public Part GetPart(int partId)
    {
        _logService.Log(className, DateTime.Now, etc...);
        return _partService.GetPart(partId);
    }

}
```

In an effort to keep my code readable and lines short, I have defined a constant string value that I pass to my logging service.

However, I am getting the compiler warning:

The field 'PartController.className' is assigned but its value is never used.

Clearly, I'm using the value here. What's odd is that in my MVC classes I don't see the warning.

Can anyone recommend a best-practice for this kind of scenario **or** a way to suppress these warnings?

Comment: Where is BuildController? Your posted sample shows the class name is PartController.

Comment: The compiler warning is referring to `BuildController`, not `PartController` - are you sure you're not just looking in the wrong file, and that in `BuildController` you're really not using it? (I can't reproduce this warning with a `const`, even when it *isn't* used - removing the `const` part gives the warning though.)

Comment: Sorry, artifact of a copy/pase. Example is a PartController. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to suppress warnings.

First, as Jimenemex highlighted, there is

```
#pragma warning disable 0169
private const string className = "My.Long.Full.ClassPath.PartController";
#pragma warning restore 0169
```

There is also a [suppression attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview), which is not recommended for a lot of suppressions in release code because of performance.

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1039:ListsAreStrongTyped")]
```

You can also create a cs file to hold suppression attributes, then target suppressions with attribute properties

```
[module: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1020:AvoidNamespacesWithFewTypes", Scope = "namespace", Target = "MyNamespace")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution. For some reason this was a Visual Studio bug. It can be fixed by restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the warning, add this around the declaration of `className`. This [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/index) has a bunch of warnings to suppress if that one is not the one. The warning number should also be in the output window, next to the warning.

```
#pragma warning disable 0169, 414, 0219 // I forgot which one it is.
private const string className = "My.Long.Full.ClassPath.PartController";
#pragma warning restore 0169, 414, 0219
```

I think you also can get around it by making it `public` but I'm not sure.